# How Synchronization works in StringBuffer?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, stringbuffer

I read all the time that StringBuffer is thread safe, but I never understood how it is implemented. I do not see any `synchronized` keyword in the method definition in documentation. Does Java use `synchronized` blocks? Are all methods `synchronized`? I believe only the methods that update the underlying object should be `synchronized`.

Comment: Most of the methods are `synchronized`.  You can see that by opening the code in your IDE.

Comment: See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuffer.java). Yes, most of methods are synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

> String buffers are safe for use by multiple threads. The methods are synchronized where necessary so that all the operations on any particular instance behave as if they occur in some serial order that is consistent with the order of the method calls made by each of the individual threads involved.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

If you are interested on how this is implemented in detail, install the Oracle JDK with source code and look directly into StringBuffer.java or [look here for an Apache Licensed online version](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/StringBuffer.java).

Comment: why the read methods are synchronized? How do read methods impact multi threaded operations. If an object is being updated (not done yet) then the read methods would return old value, which sounds correct. Why acquire a lock while reading?

Comment: @codeCrawler: I can see private read method only with below signature:  private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)

Comment: @Ravindrababu by read i mean methods like ,   `length() getChars()` they are synchronized!

Comment: That is safe guard. When you are appending, you won't get intermediate results since append does not release object lock and length() and getChars() will for append to complete.

Comment: @Ravindrababu what will happen if the `getChars()` is called during update is happening,  will it return old value or whatever is updated so far?

Comment: If no one locked StringBuffer object, getChars() will return current value. If some lokced StringBuffer object (say append()) method, getChars() will wait till append() completes and return latest value.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer` is thread safe. `append` method is synchronized.

Look [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuffer.java/?v=source) for more details.

```html
/**
 * A thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters.
 * A string buffer is like a {@link String}, but can be modified. At any
 * point in time it contains some particular sequence of characters, but
 * the length and content of the sequence can be changed through certain
 * method calls.
 * <p>
 * String buffers are safe for use by multiple threads. The methods
 * are synchronized where necessary so that all the operations on any
 * particular instance behave as if they occur in some serial order
 * that is consistent with the order of the method calls made by each of
 * the individual threads involved.
```

```
public synchronized StringBuffer append(Object obj) {
    super.append(String.valueOf(obj));
    return this;
}

public synchronized StringBuffer append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

*EDIT:*

Regarding your query on

> what will happen if the getChars() is called during update is happening, will it return old value or whatever is updated so far?

the answer is:

getChars() will wait till other synchronized methods complete the execution and release lock.

If you refer to second paragraph on documentation, it clearly quoted that operations behave as if they occur in serial order.